# How to make when hover an image to change color and arrow of the button to make transparent

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on project with VueJS add vutify. I have created the  component v-card vutify. Into v-card I have v-img, v-card-action which into it I have set text  and button to separate each side.
I am sharing my link on code pene what I have done until now just as example.

[enter link description here][1]

I want to achieve  effect when I click hover image to change color and  arrow  into of the button to make transparent. Any idea?

Exactly as the link I am sharing below.

[enter link description here][2]
[1]: https://codepen.io/venallanaj/pen/PoEbKYx

Answer (score 0):

The link you provided does not work.  Please supply a valid example.  Also, please clarify your question.  What element/s do you want to change color?  Do, you want the elements to change color when the mouse is hovered over the element?

To change color of an element when you hover over the element you could grab the element in CSS and then add the ::hover selector to produce the results.

For example, the following would change the behavior of the input element when the mouse is overed over it.

```
`input {
border-radius: 2px;
border: 1px solid lightgray;
color: rgb(100, 100, 100);
background-color: transparent;
height: 28px;
line-height: 0;
transition: 0.5s;
}
input:hover{
border: 1px solid black;
color: black;
cursor: pointer;
transition: 0.5s;
}`
```